# Training loss curve decrease sharply

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am new at deep learning.
I have a dataset with 1001 values of human pose upper body. The model I trained for that has 4 Conv layers and 2 fully connected layers with ReLu and Dropout. This is the result I got after 200 iterations. Does anyone have any ideas about why the curve of training loss decreases in a sharp way?
I think probably I need more data, as my dataset concludes numerical values what do you think is the best data augmentation method I have to use here?

[image: please check the photo]

Comment: I think some more details are needed: is your dataset made by images (you speak about "values")? why in your picture, despite the title, there is just one curve? you talk about 200 iterations (epochs?) but the x-axis report far lower values, why? Are you trying to do regression or classification? Which loss are you employing? Did you try any well-known model for your task? Is there missing a pooling layer in your architecture?

Comment: Please provide an information what values can we see at the x-axis, it should be tangled with number of iterations. Maybe you show loss at every epoch?

Comment: @nsacco First sorry for the late answer, I just zoom-in the photo to show you the curve. My dataset is 1000*36 of numbers that are from the MoCap Dataset. It is a regression problem and this is the training loss curve.

Comment: @s3nh First sorry for the late answer, I just zoom-in the photo to show you the curve. My dataset is 1000*36 of numbers that are from the MoCap Dataset. It is a regression problem and this is the training loss curve. No this is not the loss at every epoch, I have checked it with different number of iterations 200 up to 700